# Does a Cuban citizen need a transit visa to travel from the UAE to Cuba via Russia?

Tags: transit-visas, russia, cuban-citizens

Do I need a transit visa to travel from the UAE to Cuba via Russia?
I am a resident of the UAE and I'm a Cuban national.

Comment: @pnuts Edited to uae-citizens

Comment: And uae residency. Do we have a tag for it?

Answer (score 5):

No, as stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=CU&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=RU&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), you do not even need a visa to **visit** Russia, so you definitely don't need one to change planes without entering the country.